# Website Statistics Program for IIS Based Websites (.Net)

Tags: asp.net, iis, analytics, logging

I am looking for a server-installed website statistics/analytics program that runs using .Net 3.5 or earlier (not CGI). I have found several old packages that run via CGI which will not work for me. I also found a package like SmarterTools SmarterStats which will not work due to the .Net 4.0 requirement. If anyone can recommend a server side stats tool for IIS, I'd sincerely appreciate it.

Shannon

Comment: Do you want to measure traffic or performance?

Answer (score 0):

See if this can be of any help to you : http://blog.getglimpse.com/2011/11/01/glimpse-0-86-released/